# Struts 2 setting dispatcher:FORWARD makes struts.actionMapping to noActionMapping

Tags: jsp, filter, struts2, httprequest

To get the `struts.actionMapping` in jsp or tags we use `struts.actionMapping` of `request`
as an example this :

```
 <s:property value="#request['struts.actionMapping']"/>
```

Shows some thing like:

```
ActionMapping{name='own-to-other-form', namespace='/transaction/fundtransfer',
              method='form', extension='ib', params={}, result=null}
```

Actually we use `<s:property value="#request['struts.actionMapping'].name"/>` to get action name.

When I change the `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` to  `<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>`

The above tag shows `noActionMapping`.

Is there any way I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The value for `struts.actionMapping` can be found in the context.

You can print the value in JSP using

```xml
<s:property value="#context['struts.actionMapping']"/>
```

Comment: The result is empty. I also test `<s:property value="#context"/>` the result is empty too.

Comment: Normally it works, but if you have errors in the code you should post them